# Laravel Voyager: Call to undefined method TCG\Voyager\ getCoordinates()

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I have defined a field `location` as Spatial in a model that extends a Voyager model. But I keep getting a `BadMethodCallException`
`Call to undefined method TCG\Voyager\Models\User::getCoordinates()`

when I try to access the BREAD.

Here is the Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Spatial;

class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User
{
    use Notifiable;
    use Spatial;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * Map Coordinate fields
     */
    protected $spatial = [
        'location'
    ];
}
```

I have also tried setting the location column to type GEOMETRY and POINT in the schema. But I suspect that has nothing to do with this.

I'm using Laravel 7 and Voyager 1.4

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't have two lines with `use`. This should solve the problem.

```
class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User
{
    use Notifiable, Spatial;
    ...
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem. I'm using only one line of use right now like you showed but the same error still occurs.

I've tried doing a php artisan cache:clear but that didn't help either.

Comment: @MrEduar from where you find that we can't use `use` more than once?